# Calling number from dialpad returns warning: "Call requires permission which may be rejected by user"

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-permissions

I am trying to basically dial a number when the user clicks on a TextView that has a number:

```
number_title.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                        callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:+"+user.getTelephone()));
                        activity.startActivity(callIntent);
                        //the above line returns the warning given below
                    }
});
```

The warning I get:

> Call requires permission which may be rejected by user. Code to
>   explicitly check to see if the permission is available

I understand that the app needs to request permission if the permission hasn't been granted before. My question is, how do I request the permission explicitly before making the call?

Comment: This is about runtime permissions, isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this is about runtime permission, so only declaring them in manifest won't work. Instead you have to check the permission right before you start the call.

Something like this should work - the user will only be asked for the permission if he hasn't granted it before (or if he revoked it):

```
private static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CALL_PHONE = 1234;

public void yourfunction() {
    number_title.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,
                                                Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE)
                                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity,
                            new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE},
                            MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CALL_PHONE);
                    } else {
                        executeCall();
                    }
                }
    });
}

private void executeCall() {
    // start your call here
    activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:+"+user.getTelephone()));
            activity.startActivity(callIntent);         
        }
    });
}


@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
    String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CALL_PHONE: {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                // permission was granted, yay!
                executeCall();


            } else {

                // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                // functionality that depends on this permission.
            }
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

I took the above code mainly from google:
http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html
Visit the link if you want to have more information.

Edit:
`onRequestPermissionsResult` will be a callback function in your activity. You may have to handle the call there.

Answer (score 2):

This is just a sample of reference call for checking the permission:

```
if(!checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission. CALL_PHONE)==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

    requestPermissions(this,new String {}(Manifest.permission. CALL_PHONE),INT_TO_CHECK RESULT);

}
```

Let me know if this works.

Edited: Made changes in the code to explain.

Comment: Can you show that in a Sample code please? A bit confused what to substitute in place of the variables you've shown

Comment: Also check the link for adding runtime permission.
http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/things-you-need-to-know-about-android-m-permission-developer-edition/en

Comment: What is checkSelfPermission? and what is requestPermissions? I get errors for those

Comment: @Earthling: You need to read the developer's guide for this. 
Google has explained it very nicely. 
For your reference I have also given you a link which explains the above two functions pretty nicely.
http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/things-you-need-to-know-about-android-m-permission-developer-edition/en

Read them, if you still can't figure out after. I will help you.

Comment: Thank you! I will gi through them. Thanks for taking the time

Comment: Welcome. Let me know if this works and if it does accept it as a answer.

Answer (score 0):

use this may this will work  :

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Comment: This won't help. The question is about runtime permissions.

Comment: i think you are you using any third party application or any anti virus application for blocking for permissions.

Comment: I want to request permissions for Call_phone during runtime. I've already added these to the manifest